# Is there a way to sum key values of one single attribute in a JSON file in Python?

Tags: python, json

So I have a JSON file with mutiple categories and quantities attributes. I need to sum the quantites of each category separately but I'm not sure I can do that (or how I would).

This is the code I have so far:

```
    for key, value in broken_database:

        if value and "quantity" in value.keys():
            sum += value["quantity"]

    print(sum)
```

It gives me back this error message:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

And even if it ran, this code wouldn't be enough because it would just sum all the quantities attribute and I need to sum per category

I expected this to at least sum everything so then I could figure it out how to separate the categories but so far all I get is errors.

EDIT: This is a part of the JSON file:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1316334,
    "name": "Refrigerador bottom Freezer Electrolux de 02 Portas Frost Free com 598 Litros",
    "quantity": 12,
    "price": 3880.23,
    "category": "Eletrodom\u00e9sticos"
  },
  {
    "id": 1911864,
    "name": "Mouse Gamer Predator cestus 510 Fox Preto",
    "price": 699.0,
    "category": "Acess\u00f3rios",
    "quantity": 0
  },
```

EDIT: Now I have this code:

```
import json

with open("broken_database.json", "r+", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    broken_database = json.load(file)

    for key in broken_database:
        estoque = sum(key["quantity"] for key in broken_database)
        print(estoque)

with open("broken_database.json", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    json.dump(broken_database, file, indent=2)

print(broken_database)
```

It sums all of the "quantity" attribute but it doesn't separate the sum by the "category" attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data structure of your JSON object is a list of dicts, so you should iterate over it without unpacking key-value pairs, and obtain the dict values of `quantity` directly by key instead:

```
sum(d['quantity'] for d in broken_database)
```

EDIT: Since you now mention in the comment that you'd like the sums to be grouped by the `category` attribute, you can make the output a dict instead, named `sums` in the following example:

```
sums = {}
for d in broken_database:
     sums[d['category']] = sums.get(d['category'], 0) + d['quantity']
```

Comment: using reduce would be faster i think

Comment: No, `reduce` would be much slower since it would produce a separate integer object for every add operation it performs, while `sum` would perform fast additions over one integer variable in C.

Comment: it would ? isn't it lazy ?

Comment: No, `reduce` isn't lazy, since it requires aggregation of results from prior calculations. It needs to keep producing new objects in order to apply the reduction function towards the next item in the iterable.

Comment: That worked for half of the problem, I can now sum all of the "quantity" attribute, now I need to figure out how to separate the sum by the "category" attribute as well

Comment: Oh :/ i thought it would be lazy just like `map` and `filter`. Is it why it has been removed from builtin ?

Comment: @AliciaAlves I see. Separating the sums by the category is a new requirement that is not in your question. I've updated my answer accordingly then.

Comment: @Nenri Exactly. The poor performance of `reduce` is exactly why it was removed from builtins.

Comment: @blhsing I'm sorry, with so many edits I made that part ended up getting lost between the codes

Answer (score 1):

I've updated the code based on your JSON data. It seems the `broken_database` is list. If that's the case then you simply need to loop through the a list values using `for value in broken_database:`.

```
sum = 0
for value in broken_database:
    if value and "quantity" in value.keys():
        sum += value["quantity"]
    print(sum)
```

**Update:** If you want sum by category, you can store the sums inside a dictionary `sum_by_category`:

```
sum_by_category = {}
for value in broken_database:
    category = value["category"]
    if category not in sum_by_category:
        sum_by_category[category] = 0
    if value and "quantity" in value.keys():
        sum_by_category[category] += value["quantity"]

print(sum_by_category)
```

Comment: I had tried the for loop but it gave me another error, now I have the following: `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not dict`

Comment: I've updated the code based on your JSON data. I thought `broken_database` was supposed to be dictionary type so I used `for key in broken_database:` but based on your given json data, it appears to be a list. I've updated my answer so that it used `for value in broken_database:` instead. Let me know if it still reports any errors.

Comment: It worked greatly now! but it still doesn't separate the sum by the "category" attribute, it only sums the "quantity" attribute